# What data type is being returned on this Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I'm trying to figure out the return type. It looks like ToList() returns a List but I'm not sure of what type.

```
 var id = (from h in db.t_ref_harvest_type
                  where h.manner_of_take_id == methodOfTakeId && 
               parsedSeasons.Contains((int)h.season) && h.active == true
                  select new { h.id, h.harvest_type }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **List of Anonymous type** returned which is having **id and type** as property in it.

when you write Select new in linq query it creates anonymous type with the property you have specefied in select new {}.

[image]

Full aritlce : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

**EDIT**

@KeelRisk - you cannot return list of anonymous type from the method...if you just want to return id than modify query select to "`List<int> lstid= (.....Select h.id).ToList<int>();`" and than return lstid..will do to you

```
List<int> lstid = (from h in db.t_ref_harvest_type                  
 where h.manner_of_take_id == methodOfTakeId && parsedSeasons.Contains((int)h.season)
 && h.active == true                   
select h.id ).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok then what type should be returned in my method? It is just returning var id. Or better put how do I return a List of Anonymous type?

Comment: @KeelRisk - you cannot return list of anonymous type from the method...if you just want to return id than modify query select to "List<int> lstid= (.....Select h.id).ToList<int>();" and than return lstid..will do to you

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to loop through the results and the take out the ids. thanks